# I am getting junk output also

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

I'm trying to reverse a string with the Reverse function.   If I put size of the output array 10 and give 10 values as input , i give the perfect output. But if i initialize the size of output array with str.size() it gives some garbage value also.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

string Reverse(string str)
{
    cout<<str.size()<<endl;
    char output[str.size()];

    int temp = 0;
    for(int i = str.length()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        output[temp] = str[i];
        temp++;
    }
    return output;
}

int main()
{
    char st[100];
    cout<<Reverse(gets(st));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wot no `NUL` terminator?

Comment: Wrong duplicate. `output` is copied to a `std::string`. Reopened.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah, I overlooked that. You're right the `NUL` terminator is missing.

Comment: What is the input you give?

Comment: Just use [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here apart from the missing `NULL` terminator that others have already pointed out:

- Use of a deprecated and dangerous function [**`gets`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets).

  > The function provides no means to prevent buffer overflow of the destination array, given sufficiently long input string. `std::gets` was deprecated in C++11 and removed from C++14.
  >
  > `std::fgets` can be used instead.
- Use of variable length array (which can be a compiler extension) in the `Reverse` function, a feature that is not supported by standard C++.

  > `char output[str.size()];`

Since you are already using `std::string` in your program, you can use it for the `output` variable as well and that would fix your `NULL` termination issue.

And if you are not prevented from using standard library algorithms, you can use `std::reverse` instead of the `Reverse` function.

Comment: *"Use of variable length array"* why would OP use `std::string` **and** `char[]`? Using just the library string would fix this issue and the `NULL` terminating issue

Comment: Difficult for me to speculate on the intentions of the OP. I thought it would be good for him to know that VLA is not a standard feature.

Comment: I like your points, it's not my downvote, but I'd very much like to see a small in note, in the answer, regarding the use of `std::string`

Comment: @Ayxan: Added that.

Comment: Your last point is ill advice indeed. Why suggest a non-portable solution when you can call reverse on the string class, which you don’t even mention despite the fact that this answer is comprehensive in style? That’s why I downvoted.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I did not suggest to use it. I mentioned that this was one of the issues with the code. I was telling the OP to fix these issues in the code.

Comment: By all means point out the bug. Then suggest using reverse; that’s the only credible fix.

Comment: @P.W now it is perfect!